# Applying margin to th elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have to add an unnecessary `span` in my `th` elements in order to get the `margin-top` to work. Is there a CSS rule I can use to avoid this extra `span`?

http://jsfiddle.net/VywK7/1/

CSS

```
table
{
    width:100%;
    border:4px solid gray;
    padding:2px;
}
thead
{
    background-color:gray;
}
th span
{
    display:block;
    margin-top:-4px;
}
th, td
{
    padding:2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span>Month</span></th>
        <th><span>Amount</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `table { border-top-width:0; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, here is your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VywK7/4/

CSS

```
table
{
    width:100%;
    border:4px solid gray;
    padding:2px;
}
thead
{
    background-color:gray;
}
td
{
    padding:2px;
}
th
{
    padding: 0 2px 5px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-4px` margin you added is caused by the borde around the table. So try to remove the top border and you do not need the `<span>`s (and corresponding CSS) anymore:

```
table
{
    width:100%;
    border:4px solid gray;
    padding:2px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to do that because not all of my tables have a `thead`. I want those tables to still have a `border-top`