# HTML margin isn't working

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to add some margin to my table. Padding and border work but margin doesn't.

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Expon">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987102/applying-margin-to-th-elements

Comment: Consider adding a jsfiddle link with the code sample above, so it's easier for others to attempt a solution to your question.

Comment: TH/TDs can't have margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add margin you need to add table cellspacing="10"
here is my code to test , try this code....

```
  <html>
<head>

<style>
     th {
      border: 1px solid black;        
      padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="Expon" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <th>gfhd</th>
    <th>dfgh</th>
    <th>gfh</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>gfh</th>
    <th>fgh</th>
    <th>gfh</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>fgdh</th>
    <th>gfh</th>
    <th>fgh</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No doctype declaration sets truly poor example.

Comment: @bhansa There is no need for you to comment again until you learn more than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to cell-spacing, in css you can use `border-spacing` along with `border-collapse: separate` properties, applied to the parent `table` tag

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Expon">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define each margin side:

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
```

You have to define each side of the margin.
If you need more help with margins, refer to this link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use [border-spacing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/) to space between your cells, instead of using margin.

```css
th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

table{
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Expon">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```